# Why can't I see the release variant of a resource file in Android Studio?

Tags: android, android-studio

Created two new XML files - one using the `debug` qualifier and the other using the `release` qualifier.

[image]

However, I can't seem to be able to see the `release` variant in Android Studio's file navigator.

[image]

I have to manually open and edit those files using the terminal right now. Anyone know how to fix?

[image]

Comment: You might be happier with the "Project" view rather than the "Android" view that you're using now for the tree. Above the tree, choose "Project" from the drop-down. This gives you an actual filesystem view of your project.

Comment: @CommonsWare Look at this guy. Straight up Atlas over here single handedly carrying StackOverflow. Thanks a bunch. Do you happen to know any setting to make both visible from the default "Android" view by any chance?

Comment: No, sorry. I never use that view. It drives me nuts... well, OK, more nuts than normal. 